# How can I make it so that this python path search finds the correct path?

Tags: python

```
def rightMostPath(graph, root, target, path = None):
    if path == None:
        path = []
    path.append(root)
    if root == target:
        return path
    if root not in graph.keys():
       return None
    for v in graph[root]:
        if v not in path:
            ep = rightMostPath(graph, v, target, path)
            if ep:
                return ep
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = {0: [1], 1: [0, 2, 3], 2: [1], 3: [1]}
    R = rightMostPath(graph, 0, 3)
    print(R)
```

The above code will return with the answer in path as [0,1,2,3] when after drawing out this simple graph it is obvious that the path should be [0,1,3]. I wanted to know what would be causing this to happen because everywhere I look points to this type of path search for graph structures in Python.

Comment: Just in case ... the main problem is that you append **root** to the solution path *before* you know it will work; if it fails, you don't remove it.  Since **path** is passed around everywhere, that's the master copy you're updating.

Comment: So ... wither remove root from path on failure, or don't append it until you return successfully (which requires a few other changes in your logic).

Comment: I think I fixed it.  Add the line **path.remove(root)** just before each spot where you **return None**.  I now get the expected output for that case, and the logical flow looks like a DFS to these aging eyes.

Comment: thank you very much that worked, @Prune

Comment: Great!  I'll write this up as an answer, then.  Please accept / upvote / whatever so that SO can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you append **root** to the solution **path** before you know it will work; if it fails, you don't remove it. Since **path** is passed around everywhere, that's the master copy you're updating -- the failed node is still in the path.  Every node you visit, whether or not it contributes to a solution, appears in your final copy.

Either remove **root** from **path** on failure, or don't append it until you return successfully (which requires a few other changes in your logic).

Quick solution: add the line

```
path.remove(root)
```

just before each spot where you return **None**. I now get the expected output for that case, and the logical flow looks like a DFS to these aging eyes.

```
def rightMostPath(graph, root, target, path = None):
    if path == None:
        path = []
    path.append(root)
    if root == target:
        return path
    if root not in graph.keys():
       path.remove(root)  # Restore path
       return None
    for v in graph[root]:
        if v not in path:
            ep = rightMostPath(graph, v, target, path)
            if ep:
                return ep

    path.remove(root)  # Restore path
    return None
```